# Current Xamarin app not on emulator?

Tags: c#, xamarin

When I start the xamarin emulator I cant find the app im working on, why is that?

I've restarted my visual studio a couple of times but it doesnt work.

Comment: Only a magic mirror can help (joke). Very little information. Read this and look for answers - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/

Comment: Have you checked the deploy option?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the emulator's IP address. If you use Android emulators for Visual Studio, press `Tools` (last icon on right with two arrows) and locate it under Network details.

After that open `Tools - Android - Android Adb Command Prompt` in Visual Studio.

Here you type in: `adb connect *IP address*` (without stars)